# Is there anyway for to bring installed programs from one ubuntu pc to another?

Tags: installation

Is there anyway for to bring installed programs from one ubuntu pc to another, without installing it from the Software centre? I am having problems trying to install MyPaint on my desktop, though there was no problem on my netbook.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the package as a tar/package and then install the package via the command prompt.  Is the goal just to bypass the Software centre?  http://mypaint.intilinux.com/?page_id=6